# Add a button for each item in a collection

Tags: swift, class, func

How can I add a button for each available item in my collection, without writing the code once for each item?

This is what I have so far:

```
func drawInventory() {

    if Person.inventory.itemsInBag[0].Id > 0 {
        let itemButton1 = UIButton()
        itemButton1.setImage(Person.inventory.itemsInBag[0].Image, for: .normal)
        itemButton1.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 185, width: 30, height: 30)
        itemButton1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapItemInInventory), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(itemButton1)
    }
    if Person.inventory.itemsInBag[1].Id > 0 {
        let itemButton1 = UIButton()
        itemButton1.setImage(Person.inventory.itemsInBag[1].Image, for: .normal)
        itemButton1.frame = CGRect(x: 300+40, y: 185, width: 30, height: 30)
        itemButton1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapItemInInventory2), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(itemButton1)
    }


}

func tapItemInInventory() {
    print(self.Person.inventory.itemsInBag[0].Name + "Pressed")
}

func tapItemInInventory2() {
    print(self.Person.inventory.itemsInBag[1].Name + "Pressed")

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func drawInventory() {
    Person.inventory.itemsInBag.enumerated().filter { $1.Id > 0 }.enumerated().forEach { index, itemAndIndex in
        let (itemPosition, item) = itemAndIndex
        let itemButton = UIButton()

        itemButton.setImage(item.Image, for: .normal)
        itemButton.frame = CGRect(x: 300 + (40 * itemPosition), y: 185, width: 30, height: 30)
        itemButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapItemInInventory(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        itemButton.tag = index
        view.addSubview(itemButton)
    }
}

dynamic func tapItemInInventory(_ button: UIButton) {
    let item = Person.inventory.itemsInBag[button.tag]

    print(item.Name + "Pressed")
}
```

Here, `itemButton`'s `tag` property is used to identify which item it pertains to. It is the *quick and dirty* way of passing information around, but works well for this simple example.

A better solution would be subclass `UIButton`, adding it a property to reference the item it is related to.

Also, `enumerated()` is called twice. The first time, we get the item's index in `itemsInBag` array. The second time, we get the item position on screen, as we may discard some items if its Id is less than 0.

Comment: IS the `map` necessary? Can't `enumerated` be called directly on a collection?

Comment: Good call. It was just me forgetting to remove keywords... Thanks!

Comment: @Тимур-Хасанов I updated my answer, I wrote the selector in obective-c style.